# Robocopy, Multi-Line Execute Process SSIS Task, or Output Batch File Results to SSIS

Tags: ssis, batch-file, robocopy

I need to robocopy files from one location to another in a SSIS package.  Since the folder is on another domain, I need to impersonate another account before I run the robocopy.exe command.  I found I can execute a "net use" command to impersonate the necessary user account and then execute the robocopy command immediately afterwards.  I don't see any way to do this in an Execute Process command to do this directly, so I use an Execute Process task to run a batch file that has these two commands as separate lines.  The downside of this approach is that I cannot read the results of the Execute Process command.  So this leads me to three questions:

1. Is there a way to execute a multi-line command in a single Execute Process task?
2. Is there a way to execute robocopy.exe while impersonating another account in one line?
3. Is there a way to write the results of a batch file back to either a variable in SSIS or to the SSIS database log?

If there is a positive answer for any of the above three questions, then I may be able to work out a way to add job success or failure rules based on the results of the robocopy command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be achived if you have enabled the use of the Extended Stored Procedure "xp_cmdshell" (see Books Online for "Surface Area Configuration").

In the following sample I have build a .CMD file containing all my ROBOCOPY options and simple executes this command file using xp_cmdshell grabbing the output to a table variable (can be a persistent table instead):

Just add a Execute T-SQL statement Task to your SSIS package with the following statement:

```
/** START **/

DECLARE @cmdfile nvarchar(255) = N'C:\myFolder\myCommandFile.cmd'
DECLARE @logtable table (
    [RowId] integer IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,[Message] nvarchar(1024) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @logtable ([Message])
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmdfile

SELECT *
FROM @logtable
WHERE
[Message] IS NOT NULL

/** END **/
```

Depending on your logging options set for the ROBOCOPY command you can show progress, headers, report or more. See the ROBOCOPY documentation for those options. Also try use the /TEE switch if to grab any console output from the ROBOCOPY command.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing this is to execute a batch command ( so you can execute multiple line items) with `RUNAS` (to impersonate another user account)

You can capture the output of the batch file in a log file and read the contents of that into SSIS using the Script.

I am not sure on how to write to the SSIS log and am interested to see what other developers have to say about that.

Comment: That's a good idea as an alternative to net use.  I'll see if I can combine runas into one row with robocopy.exe.  If it has to be executed as a separate command line, then net use is already adequate for my purposes.

Comment: The runas command does not have a parameter for password.  Instead, it prompts you for a password.  Googling solutions for that problem came up with using net use as an alterative or echoing the password from some other source.  I don't believe that is a step forward in solving the problem.  :(  I also don't want to build a dependency on another program that executes runas with a password as some of the other runas password problem solutions suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found two round-about methods for getting data from a batch file execution into the database.  One method is to add logging to the actual batch file.  I haven't tried this yet, but it seems conceptually possible.  The other option I have tried that has worked is to put the batch file execution as a SQL Server Agent job step and add flat-file logging.  After I did this, I created a small package that scrapes the file for specific messages.  I would still prefer a better solution, but this works well enough for now.

Comment: Claus had a better solution.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute a multi-line command in a single Execute
>   Process task?

Yes, use "Cmd.exe" as executable
Create a `string` variable with following expression (sample):

```
*"/C \"start robocopy c:\\temp\\v10.2a c:\\temp\\v1 *.WRI /Z /S && start robocopy c:\\temp\\v10.2a c:\\temp\\v1 *.dll /Z /S\""*
```

And then map to the arguments parameter via component expression. Then you can execute those two (or more) robocopy in //